# Android Studio : " No JVM installation found. Please install a 32-bit JDK "

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i read a lot about this problem , still can't figure out what is im doing wrong ?

this is a picture of my settings :

[image]

any idea ?

Update : [ As you see in the picture , im using `java 8` , is it wrong ? ]

Comment: Did you install JDK 32 bit ?

Comment: then make sure you are adding correct PATH of JDK 32 bit and with the name **JAVA_HOME**

Comment: If you take look on the picture i posted youll see the JAVA_HOME. did i do that wrong ?

Comment: I see you are using **JDK_HOME**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your environment variables dialog shows you have a variable called `JDK_HOME` listed, whereas the error message is telling you to call it `JAVA_HOME`.

You are also using a version of Java that isn't compatible with Android. You'll need to use Java 6 or 7 instead. The latest Java 7 release can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Comment: i dont understand . i added the variable `JDK_HOME` , but when i run the Android Studio , it tells me `No JVM installation found. Please install a 32-bit JDK `

Comment: @user2077916 `JDK_HOME` is not the same as `JAVA_HOME`, change the name of the environment variable to `JAVA_HOME`. You may also need to install Java 7 as 8 is not supported on Android.

Comment: i can't believe i missed that !! you made my day. now its workin !

Comment: the second part of the answer helped me out here. my Java version was 8 and now i'm going for a jdk-7u75 . i think that will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try Searching with windows where the jdk is, then target your system variable to that location.. 
hope this help

Comment: That's the Answers, Thanks